# adding list into dataframe python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have the following function to take just the time from all the timestamp that I have

```
def toTime(dataandtime):
    data, time = dataandtime
    return time
```

this what *time* present

```
#time = df.timestamp.str.split().tolist()
#type (time) out: list
print toTime(time[0])
print toTime(time[1])
print toTime(time[2])
```

Out :

```
00:01:04
00:36:34
00:37:27
```

Then, I want to take the variable `time` and store it to new list or pandas Var

```
for i in time:
    newtime = toTime(i)
    print newtime
```

Out():

```
  00:01:04
  00:36:34
  00:37:27
  00:43:05
  00:45:26
```

My question is how can I store this into new var and adding it to my dataframe?

what i need is time will be in my df as a new column

Comment: Instead of printing append the newtime to a list and give to a dataframe column.like time_list = [],then in for loop use time_list.append(toTime(i)). At the end df['Time'] = time_list.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa same error show up TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: I suggest you to provide the exact variable **time**. So that it gives an idea how the real data looked and how to get the desired output. @user2144768

Comment: @SandeepKadapa i update the question can you see it now

Comment: there is no need to use an intermediate list, use `apply` on the dataframe:
`dataframe.assign(time=dataframe.timestamp.apply(toTime))`

Comment: @GregorSturm ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Provide the values of **time** variable as original one that you are working. like if it is a list = ['00:01:05','00:20:07'],etc. If you provide instead of printing then it will be easy to provide solution @user2144768